# Getting magneticHeading value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, compass-geolocation

Can I get the magnetic heading value on the following delegate? If so, how can I get it into a `UILabel`?

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yup:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading {
    myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [newHeading magneticHeading]];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. But i used already. its not showing the heading value. i wired even in IB file also. but it doesnt occur. Help me yar :-(

Comment: @adhees: What have to tried so far to debug? Have you set a breakpoint on the line to make the delegate is even wired up right? Then try NSLogging the label at that point to make sure it's not nil. Standard sanity checks...